# Replace correlated subquery with join

Tags: greatest-n-per-group, abap, opensql, cds

I'd like to replace the following ABAP OpenSQL snippet (in the where clause of a much bigger statement) with an equivalent join.

```
... AND tf~tarifart = ( SELECT MAX( tf2~tarifart ) FROM ertfnd AS tf2 WHERE tf2~tariftyp = e1~tariftyp AND tf2~bis >= e1~bis AND tf2~ab <= e1~ab ) ...
```

My motivation: Query migration to ABAP CDS views (basically plain SQL with in comparison somewhat reduced expressiveness). Alas, correlated subqueries and EXISTS statements are not supported.

I googled a bit and found a possible solution (last post) here https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3824523

However, the proposal

> 1. Selecting MAX(value)
> 2. Your scenarion using inner join to first CDS view

doesn't work in my case.

1. tf.bis (and tf.ab) need to be in the selection list of the new view to limit the rhs of the join (new view) to the correct time frames.
2. Alas, there could be multiple (non overlapping) sub time frames (contained within [tf.ab, tf.bis]) with the same tf.tarifart.
   Since these couldn't be grouped together, this results in multiple rows on the rhs.

The original query does not have a problem with that (no join -> no Cartesian product).

I hope the following fiddle (working example) clears things up a bit: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d1f48/3

Given these constraints, to me it seems that an equivalent join is indeed impossible. Suggestions or even confirmations?

Comment: Hi. This is an sql faq, just google re using join of a subquery instead of in or exists or a scalar subquery. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please make your post self-contained, quote relevant parts from a link essential to your question. How did googling your title & variants not help you? It's not clear what you're trying to say re "return one row at max"--do you mean, it's not correlated, the same value is used for every tf row? How does the linked suggestion not work? Can you explain your limitations, eg "fear" & "can't group"?

Comment: Support philipx/ Place your **full** query, not this useless piece

Comment: Suggestion: Build a second CDS view that does the MAX grouping. Then join your original select to that other view.

Comment: How would I do that without "group by" on tf2~bis? I need the tf2~bis to determine the correct MAX( tf2~tarifart ) for a specific date...

Comment: Doing this without group by is another faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. PS [tag:greatest-n-per-group] PS Google 'stackexchange notifications' re notifying a non-poster among multiple commenters via *@username*. PS Please: clarify writing & include code & quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
select doc_belzart,
       doc_tariftyp,
       doc_ab,
       doc_bis,
       max(tar_tarifart)
  from 
  (
    select document.belzart as doc_belzart, 
           document.tariftyp as doc_tariftyp,  
           document.ab as doc_ab,
           document.bis as doc_bis, 
           tariff.tarifart as tar_tarifart,
           tariff.tariftyp as tar_tariftyp,
           tariff.ab as tar_ab,
           tariff.bis as tar_bis
      from dberchz1 as document
      inner join ertfnd as tariff
        on tariff.tariftyp = document.tariftyp and
           tariff.ab <= document.ab and
           tariff.bis >= document.bis
  ) as max_tariff
  group by doc_belzart,
          doc_tariftyp,
          doc_ab,
          doc_bis
```

Translated in English, you seem to want to determine the max applicable tariff for a set of documents.

I'd refactor this into separate steps:

1. Determine all *applicable* tariffs, meaning all tariffs that completely cover the document's time interval. This will become your first CDS view, and in my answer forms the sub-query.
2. Determine for all documents the max applicable tariff. This will form your second CDS view, and in my answer forms the outer query. This one has the MAX / GROUP BY to reduce the result set to one per document.